# Facing SSL issue with Qpid Python Proton library when using Amazon Linux 2 / Lambda using Python 3.10

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, openssl, amazon-linux-2, qpid-proton

We are building an AWS ActiveMQ project using Lambda (runs on Amazon Linux 2), which uses Qpid proton library from Apache. The issue ultimately seems to be that the Qpid library is unable to locate SSL on the system. The same code works fine in Ubuntu and Windows (running the same versions) but fails in Lambda.

Here is what I have tried so far:

I verified that SSL is available in Python with the command below:

```py
import ssl;
print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)
# prints:
# OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fip
```

But when I try to run the following it fails:

```py
import proton;
print('%s' % 'SSL present' if proton.SSL.present() else 'SSL NOT Available')
# prints Not available
```

Here are the versions I tried:
Python 3.8, 3.9, 3.10 and 3.11
Qpid 0.39.0

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you install this gcc and try? Use this command sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++ cmake openssl-devel cyrus-sasl-devel swig

Comment: Yes, I have installed all the dependencies including the extra ones below per (https://github.com/apache/qpid-proton/blob/6b05c6d64ba04bad96745b1430ca17d436b6fd32/INSTALL.md)

yum install openssl-devel
yum install cyrus-sasl-devel cyrus-sasl-plain cyrus-sasl-md5